# window.location.hash anchor links with in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

need a fix for my below question.  would be great if any one suggest me..

my html page contains header div which is fixed. & below the fixed header div I have content div. content div is having more content with internal anchor links. so when I click on the page links the content is starting from windows top position. Because I have used "window.location.hash". So its starting from top & internal links are not showing up correctly. So can anyone plz give me a solution to make this content links to appear below the fixed header div ``

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve - even if I assume the `javascript` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with a fixed header as you said, you may need to use `window.scrollTo` instead of hash tags.  The `Y` position will be how many pixels down the page you would like to scroll to.

```
window.scrollTo(x,y);
```

Comment: I have used select drop down for months. each month is having data in table format so when I change the months in dropdown it should show the perticular months table below the fixed header div. below is the js $('.select-month').change(function() {
    var monthDiv = $(this).val();
    window.location.hash = monthDiv; and table is having <div id="month1" class="main-table"><table></table></div>

Comment: You need to target the `.offset().top` of the elements you are trying to scroll to.  Does that make sense?

Comment: can u plz send me a code . I am still learning basics of JQuery window.offset().top = monthDiv; is it correct ?

Comment: Hi . Please look in to below link. fix needed for below points.

Comment: Hi . Please look in to the below link. fix needed for below points.  1.when I select month tab it displaying content from windows top position. for ex:if I select August. content is not visible. so the link content should start below the fixed div. 2. if there is no content  for particular month selected it shl take us to last month 3. when we refresh page select dropdown should be reset. http://jsfiddle.net/RYy4t/

Comment: Yes this is amazing! It allowed me to scroll to the top of the page with window.scrollTo(0,0); - Before that I was using anchor tags and the content in the anchor was hidden under my fixed header. Life saver buddy. Nice code.